# Serialize structure into CSV file

Tags: c, csv

I can't figure out how to serialize my structure (shown below) to a file in CSV format.

My data structure is:

```
typedef struct{
  double car_plate[80][100];
  double year[80][100];
} Results;
```

How do I save it to a CSV file?

Comment: what's 80 and 100 ? How did you stock a year into a double ? Last time I see this kind of thing, it was a windows concept and it turned out to be a really bad idea ...

Comment: you'll need to open up a text file for writing, then loop through all the members of your `struct` and write each one formatted correctly to the file, with appropriate delineation for a .csv file.

Comment: Using a 2D array of `double` to hold a registration number and a year seems very peculiar.  Even if they were character arrays, you'd be better off with `typedef struct Results { char car_plate[10]; int year; } Results;` and then defining `Results array[80];` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's called Serialization. I don't think you want to put like 16 KB onto stack, but that's not important for you.

Anyway, you very propably want to use `fprintf` option with `for` loops like so:

```
Results res; //Let's assume that it's initialized.
FILE * f; //Let's say same about file.

for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++) {
        fprintf(file,"%f,%f\n", res.car_plate[x][y], res.year[x][y]);
        fflush(file);
    }
```

You have to adjust this code to your requiremets. If this doesn't meet your conditions, you always can use it as a template for solving on your own. `fflush()` is just flushing buffers, so I'm nearly 100% sure you can safetly remove it, if you are going to flush stream after operation.